# how to pass binary value while testing AWS lambda function manually

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

How can I pass binary values to lambda function while testing from AWS lambda console only?

```
"NewImage": {
      "likes": {
        "N": "5"
      },
      "is_em": {
        "B": ?????????
      },
      "id": {
        "N": "9"
      },
      "user_access_key_id": {
        "S": "ASIAJIGCYGKAOSMJN6MA"
      }
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

You can receive it within a JSON message as a base64 encoded string.

```
NewImage": {
  "likes": {
    "N": "5"
  },
  "is_em": {
    "B": "ZWFzdXJlLg=="
  },
  "id": {
    "N": "9"
  },
  "user_access_key_id": {
    "S": "ASIAJIGCYGKAOSMJN6MA"
  }
}
```